# Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql

The code-
`$sql = 'INSERT INTO kiosk_registration ( kiosk_name, mini_info, grade, domain, phonenumber,   password, referrer_id, kiosk_id, user_id)

 VALUES ("'.$_POST["name"].'", "'.$_POST["mini_info"].'", "'.$_POST["grade"].'",   "'.$_POST["domain"].'", "'.$_POST["phone_number"].'", "'.$_POST["password"].'",   "'.$_POST["ref_id"].'", "'.$kiosk_id.'", "'.$_SESSION['uid'].'")';

 if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))

 {

 die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

 }`

The error - Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'.
And this started happening on its own. It used to work perfectly fine, but this error just started appearing suddenly. I have no clue as to what could be wrong.

**Sorry guys, it was a small problem, i mixed up the files, I was updating and not inserting hence the error **

Comment: Sounds like a MySQL problem. Does the column `password` definitely exist? Could you post the schema of your table to confirm.

Comment: You really should escape stuff before inserting it into a query string.

Comment: nope, it doesn't. I would trust your database, not your opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this indicates that the kiosk_registration table has changed, and that the 'password' field no longer exists. Check the definition of the table in the database. Also: are you sure you're connecting to the database you think you're connecting to?

Answer (score 2):

It can means only one. Your table hasn't field `password`. Check the table to existing this field.